# Knockout.js: dash in binding name

Tags: json, binding, knockout.js

I'm building my first knockout.js app, and I'm having trouble with bindings.
I'm downloading some JSON from a web API, and I want to show the data on my page. The problem is that the start of the JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "application-collection": [
{  ...
```

Now when I try to bind like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: application-collection">
```

I get an error: `Message: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: application;`

When searching for this I only find questions relating to CSS, advising to put single quotes around `application-collection`. If I do that, the foreach loops through the letters (I get 22 empty list items).

So what are my options here? I'm not sure what to search for, but I'm pretty sure I'm not the first to have this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: $data['application-collection']">
```

Comment: Awesome, that works. Will accept this answer when it lets me in a few minutes